# "A might bit" or "a mite bit"?

Tags: word-usage

"That's a might/mite bit excessive, no?"

"He's more than a might/mite bit shy around the opposite gender."

"It just seems a might/mite bit offensive, is all."

Which of these is the proper spelling of the expression? I would expect it to be "mite" meaning "small," but I can't find any explicit discussion online, [Google Ngrams isn't conclusive](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20might%20bit%2C%20a%20mite%20bit&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20might%20bit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20mite%20bit%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ca%20might%20bit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20mite%20bit%3B%2Cc0), dictionaries don't list either "might" or "mite" as potential adjectives, and internet searches seem to indicate the "might bit" usage is slightly more widespread.

Comment: _A mite_ is a very small quantifier. So is _a bit_.  So one intensifies the other, and _a mite bit_ is a very very small quantifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/mite#:%7E:text=Mite%20is%20one%20of%20many,a%20bit%20and%20a%20jot.&text=Put%20away%20your%20ruler%2C%20because,words%20for%20a%20tiny%20amount), a **mite**

> is one of many words for a very small amount.

The first definition in the [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/120249?rskey=kZF6P8&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid) for mite refers to money, with a quote from the 1700s calling a mite about 1/3 of a farthing. The *widow's mite* is a well known expression for a charitable contribution made by a poor widow.

Definition #3 in the OED (same link) is a

> a very small amount

There are numerous quotes in the OED, the most recent of which is:

> 1993   T. Hawkins Pepper xii. 248   All evening he's seemed a mite
> awkward.

**The OED has no entry for mite bit, or might bit, and I did not see mite bit in any of the quotations it gave for mite.**

Thus mite is found in both current British and US English, but is somewhat of an affectation. In US English, mite is probably most common in Appalachia.  See [Daily Yonder, Mountain Talk](https://dailyyonder.com/mountain-talk/2010/07/19/)

> In the corner of Appalachia where Tennessee meets Virginia, where this
> ... can tell what part of Appalachia people come from by the words
> they use. ... Regardless of where you live in West Virginia, we are
> all blessed with a bit of that southern twang. ... A-mite — a little
> You're lookin' a-mite peak-ed today.)

As for **mite bit** in US English, I found an entry in the Urban Dictionary, which said it is "ironic", as in (quoted very loosely here) *a million might be a mite bit high for that house.*

I think the phrase **mite bit** is used mostly either ironically or as part of Southern or Appalachian dialect, but I don't have a reference for mite bit in Appalachian dialect.

It is definitely, absolutely, **not** might bit.

Comment: Thank you. I can consider this to be the definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20mite%20bit%2Ca%20might%20bit&year_start=1940&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3), both are used in American English

[image]

The same search in British English shows only "a mite bit".

Comment: Yes, but this answer currently is like saying "ain't no" and "isn't any" are both used in American English.  It's true — both expressions are used — but only one (isn't any,  mite bit) is considered "right" in educated circles.

Comment: I pretty much share my concern with Peter Shor, yeah. I emphasize that I don't look down on instances of regional language drift, although in this case it seems most likely that "might bit" is just a homophonous misspelling of a chiefly British expression and I see no reason not to just avoid it in all instances.

Comment: As a native BrEng speaker I don't recognise "a mite bit" or "a might bit" as expressions at all. I'm not saying that they don't exist but are vanishingly rare and, possibly, regional (and not in any region that I'm familiar with). I know and use "...might be _a _bit..."; "...is mighty <something>";  "...is a mite <something>"; "...is a tiny bit <something>" and would recognise "...is a _mighty_ bit <something>" but not "...is a mite bit <something>". That sounds tautological to me.

Comment: @Feryll - worth remembering that Google Ngrams indexes published books, and some US publications are re-published in Britain, so that a search for 'British English' results may produce skewed results. These may include instances of 'a mite (small insect) bit (past tense) [someone]'

Comment: @Boldben - I agree. I have never heard 'a mite bit' in any UK standard or regional dialect, or read it either, and a quick Google search for the quoted phrase 'a mite bit' shows what I see as mainly US, mainly informal sources.

Comment: @Me - Still less 'a might bit'.